# getting NullPointerException error view pager while fetching fragment method in view pager Activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, android-viewpager

I know this is very general question but can't able to figure out what is wrong.

Fragment java class

```
// newInstance constructor for creating fragment with arguments
        public static BpDetails newInstance(int page) {
            BpDetails fragmentFirst = new BpDetails();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt("someInt", page);
            fragmentFirst.setArguments(args);
            return fragmentFirst;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            page = getArguments().getInt("someInt", 0);
        }

        public String getSystolic(){

            return this.systolic.getText().toString();

        }

     /*   public String getDiastolic(){

        return this.diastolic.getText().toString();
        }*/


    // Inflate the view for the fragment based on layout XML
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bp_details, container, false);

            Log.i("View ",view.toString());

            Log.i("DOB is ",Long.toString(Constants.dob));


            systolic =(EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.systolic);
            diastolic =(EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.diastolic);


            return view;
        }
```

ViewPager Activity

```
vpPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);

        adapterViewPager = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        vpPager.setAdapter(adapterViewPager);


        findViewById(R.id.btn_prev).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // checking for last page
                // if last page home screen will be launched
                int current = getItem(-1);
                if (current!=0)
                    prevPage=current-1;
                if (current < 4) {
                    // move to next screen
                    vpPager.setCurrentItem(current);
                } else {
                    //final reached.
                }

            }
        });

        findViewById(R.id.btn_next).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // checking for last page
                // if last page home screen will be launched
                int current = getItem(+1);

                if (current!=0)
                    prevPage=current-1;

                System.out.println("Prev page "+prevPage);

                if (current < 4) {
                    // move to next screen
Fragment bpFragment=adapterViewPager.getItem(vpPager.getCurrentItem());

                    if (bpFragment instanceof BpDetails){

                        System.out.println("Current item is "+vpPager.getCurrentItem());

                        BpDetails fr = (BpDetails)adapterViewPager.getItem(vpPager.getCurrentItem());

                        **String systolicString = fr.getSystolic();** //error point

                        Log.i("Systolic is ",systolicString);
                    }


                } else {

                    //final reached.
                }
            }
        });


    }

    private int getItem(int i) {
        return vpPager.getCurrentItem() + i;
    }


    public static class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private static int NUM_ITEMS = 4;
        private static int mSelectedPosition;

        public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
            super(fragmentManager);
            //mSelectedPosition=selectedPosition;
        }

        // Returns total number of pages
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return NUM_ITEMS;
        }

        // Returns the fragment to display for that page
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0: // Fragment # 0 - This will show FirstFragment
                    return BasicDetails.newInstance(0);
                case 1:
                    return BpDetails.newInstance(1);
                case 2:
                    return BslDetails.newInstance(2);
                case 3:
                    return Summary.newInstance(3);

                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }


    }
```

Why I am getting the nullpointerException since I am accessing the public method of fragment before going to the next fragment. 
Before down voting please leave the reason of down voting so that I can improve the question.

EDit:

I got to know since I am calling the getitem() method thats why all the variable of fragment to null that why I am getting the nullpointerException. Is there any way I solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

you should rewrite your ViewPagerAdapter and store the retuened fragment

this is because every time you call getItem() function you return a new fragment,but only invoked by the viewpager itself the fragment will invoke oncreateView ,so the second time you call getItem did not initialize the  **systolic** and thus lead to **NUllPointerException**

for reference:

```
  public static class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private static int NUM_ITEMS = 4;
    private static int mSelectedPosition;
    Map<Integer,Fragment> map= new HashMap<>();

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        super(fragmentManager);
        //mSelectedPosition=selectedPosition;
    }

    // Returns total number of pages
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_ITEMS;
    }

    // Returns the fragment to display for that page
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        Fragment f = map.get(position)
        if(f!=null){
          return f;
        }
        switch (position) {

            case 0: // Fragment # 0 - This will show FirstFragment
                f = BasicDetails.newInstance(0);
            case 1:
                f = return BpDetails.newInstance(1);
            case 2:
                f = return BslDetails.newInstance(2);
            case 3:
               f = return Summary.newInstance(3);

            default:
                return null;
        }

        map.put(postion,f);
        return f;
    }


}
```